# Java Scanner class to JOptionPane class?

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

This is what this code does: Allows the user to enter one character (L or S) and three integers between 100 and 1000. The program outputs the following:

1. Display the message: “Wrong input!” if the numbers are not included in the interval [100-1000] using method `CheckInput`;
2. The largest number if the user enters the letter L, using method `Largest`;
3. The smallest number if the user enters the letter S, using method Smallest;
4. All numbers and their digits reversed using the method `Backwards`;
5. Using the method EvenOrOdd that takes one integer and outputs ‘True’ if the number is even or ‘False’ if it is odd, output the numbers entered followed by ‘True’ or ‘False’
6. Use the method `CheckDivisor`, that takes all three numbers and checks if the first number is a divisor of the second or third, and returns ‘True’ or ‘False’
7. Make the output easier to understand and add two more methods to the program

For number 7 I added, double and sum

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Words {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();

            if (line.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            }
            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            //alphabetical
            System.out.print("Alphabetical order: ");
            alphabetical(words);
            // concatenate and mix
            String[] sorted = words.clone();
            Arrays.sort(sorted);
            String all = "";
            for (String s: sorted) {
                all += s;
            }

            System.out.println("All together: " + all);
            System.out.println("Concatenate and Mix: " + mix(all));

            // find first 2 and last 2 letters
            first2last2(all);
            //middlexx
            System.out.println("Replace middle with xx or yy: " + middlexx(all));

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    private static void alphabetical(String[] words) {
        String[] ws = words.clone();
        Arrays.sort(ws);

        for (int i = 0; i < ws.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(ws[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    private static String mix(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("a|e|i|o|u", "x");
    }
    private static void first2last2(String s) {
        if (s.length() < 5) {
            System.out.println("Invalid command!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("First two characters: " + s.substring(0, 2));
            System.out.println("Last two characters: " + s.substring(s.length() - 2, s.length()));
        }
    }
    private static String middlexx(String s) {
        if (s.length() % 2 == 0) {
            return s.substring(0, s.length() / 2) + "xx" + s.substring(s.length() / 2, s.length());
        } else {
            return s.substring(0, s.length() / 2) + "yy" + s.substring(s.length() / 2 + 1, s.length());
        }
    }

}
```

How would I convert this into `JOptionPane` class? I want the program to ask the user to type `L` or `S`, and to type 3 integers using something like this:

```
String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter L or S");
a = Double.valueOf(input1).doubleValue();
```

Comment: So... that's all you have tried? Those 2 last lines? Please show a little more effort trying to solve it yourself, we're not gonna do your homework.

Comment: I have tried more, but i deleted those because they werent working @Frakcool

Comment: What wasn't working? The output wasn't the expected? You got an exception? Please post a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we can copy-paste and see where you're wrong. A sample input/output and/or the error log

Answer (score 0):

You can take input from JOptionPane like this

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "put your message here" );
```

Sample Code

```
  Object[] possibilities = {"ham", "spam", "yam"};
  String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                      frame,
                      "Complete the sentence:\n"
                      + "\"Green eggs and...\"",
                      "Customized Dialog",
                      JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                      icon,
                      possibilities,
                      "ham");

  //If a string was returned, say so.
  if ((s != null) && (s.length() > 0)) {
      setLabel("Green eggs and... " + s + "!");
      return;
  }

  //If you're here, the return value was null/empty.
  setLabel("Come on, finish the sentence!");
```

For More: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html